# vim report errors while editing a .py file in virtual environment

Tags: python, vim, virtualenv

I used [vim-spf13](http://vim.spf13.com/) to setup my vim environment.when I'm editing a .py file in virtual environment

it shows some error like this...and it disappear shortly..

[image: the error message]

Comment: Your Python install/virtual environment seems to be lacking some necessary feature. Anyway, you should open an issue on python-mode's issue tracker.

Comment: when I deactivate my venv, the error message disappeared. How can I open an issue on python-mode's issue tracker? could you be more specific? thank you~

Comment: [Do you see the big green button?](https://github.com/klen/python-mode/issues?state=closed)

Comment: seems it caused by the different python version in my virtual environment...make a change to my venv, now it worked: `[Pymode]Activate virtualenv`  still thanks!